# How can I find the email address which binds to my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support

How can I find the email address which binds to my Stack Overflow account? I have logged in already, but I forgot the email address. I want to log in on another computer.

Comment: Go to `https://<site>/users/email/settings/<yourid>`?

Comment: Should be visible [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to your profile page.
2. Click on **Edit profile and settings**.

[image]

3. On sidebar of that page, click **Edit email settings**

[image]

4. Here you get your email address.

[image]